# Netbeans permite abrir ni project ni adjuntar driver .jar

Tags: java, netbeans

Me encuentro con un problema grave y es que netbeans me inicia y me permite crar proyectos pero al darle a abrir proyecto o abrir archivo  se cierra de inmediato nisiquiera me deja elegir la ruta.

También al intentar adjuntar el driver ( .jar ) de oracle pasa lo mismo.

Cosas a saber :
-Me compre un SSD nuevo e hice una instalación limpia desde cero
-El SO que llevo en Windows 10 [Creator Update](última versión estable) build 1703
-Ya probe descargando de nuevo netbeans y desintalando y volviendo a instalar incluso restablecer el equipo de nuevo..

Pienso que es quizas por la build de windows al ser muy actual

Comment: Posiblemente un viejo **bug** de Netbeans ocurrido en 2011 ha resucitado en 2017. [Aquí hay más gente con tu problema](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200324), prueba algunas de las soluciones indicadas al final del hilo, las primeras son de 2011.

Comment: Agrego que pruebes viendo la consola de java y ver si te arroja algun error cuando pasa el crash.
En el Panel de control de Java, clic en el separador Avanzado.
Ampliar la opción Consola de Java.
Seleccionar Mostrar consola y hacer clic en Aceptar

Comment: Puedes revisar los [error log](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile)  y otra cosa, por si no lo estás haciendo así, ejecuta NetBeans como administador de Windows.

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos vere si logro pillar solucion y avisare..

Comment: pudiste resolver el problema de tu NetBeans

Comment: Se solucionó quitando el acceso directo al "Modo Dios" que estaba en el escritorio...

Comment: A mi también se me solucionó el problema eliminando el icono de acceso directo de "modo Dios" que estaba en el escritorio. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Se solucionó quitando el acceso directo al "Modo Dios" que estaba en el escritorio.

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques tu respuesta como aceptada, así se entenderá que quedó respondida.